# To run external app from cmd using python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I need a python script which will run an external application on cmd and provide the output in a text file.

Manually it is working fine for me when i run cmd as administrator and running the following command.

```
    'C:\Program Files\Decoder>decoder -o hex.txt L3 0803'.
```

I am getting proper output in hex.txt file as required.
I am trying do this with the help of a python script as follows :

```
import subprocess

cmd = "C:\Program Files\Decoder>decoder -o hex.txt L3 0803"
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

I am not getting the required output.

Comment: What output do you get, and how does it differ from what you want?  It is difficult to see what your question is.  By the way, your \ should be either escaped, or use a raw string:  `cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Decoder>decoder -o hex.txt L3 0803"`.  also read the documentation about supplying arguments in a list on Windows.

Comment: Does it throw an error, or are you suppressing an OSError?   Try it with command as a list:  ``subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Decoder>decoder', '-o', 'hex.txt', 'L3', '0803']).communicate()``

Comment: @cdarke application path is "C:\Program Files\Decoder" only. after that it is command line syntax to decode 0803 hex dump with decoder and copy that decoded output to hex.txt file.

Comment: @nephlm I am trying to do following steps : 1.To run the decoder in command line 2. Pass and L3 layer hex 3. To save decoded messages into a text file , hext.txt.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation, `Popen` expects a list and not a string.

Moreover you have a path error in your command (`>` should be `\`) and you need to escape backslashes.

try with

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["C:\\Program Files\\Decoder\\decoder", "-o", "hex.txt", "L3", "0803"]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Comment: `Popen` does not expect only a list on either Windows or POSIX. Windows `CreateProcess` takes a command-line string because every program is free to parse the command line however it wants. If you pass a list, `subprocess.list2cmdline` turns it back into a string following the MSVC rules, but that won't always work, so sometimes it's necessary to use a string instead of a list. On POSIX systems you need a string when using `shell=True`, which has the shell parse the command line. Otherwise the parameters are passed as arguments for the shell itself.

Comment: This should work: `cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Decoder\decoder -o hex.txt L3 0803";` `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd);` `p.wait()`.

Comment: @eryksun after running this I am getting error "windows error: not a valid win32 application"

Comment: @Francesco :There is no path error actually, C:\Program Files\Decoder is the decoder path  after that it is the provided command line syntax to decode the L3 hex and save it to a text file in decoder documentation.

Comment: That error means that either `decoder` or `decoder.exe` exists but isn't a Windows PE executable. What files are in the following list? `[x for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Program Files\Decoder') if x.lower().startswith('decoder')]`